# Corrupted Hard Drive Replace or Repair?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, bsod

The problem:

For about a year now my laptop's drives have been giving me error notifications such as ["Scan drive for errors",](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NamKf.png) and I've tried to use `chkdsk` and `sfc` to resolve the issues, but half a year ago my OS just completely wiped itself.

When I tried to boot up my laptop it would go into a BSoD loop then give me [this screen here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XnWf.png) So I reinstalled the OS again and I'm now currently in this loop where my drive completely wipes itself then I reinstall Windows 10 and have the drive be usable for about 1-2 months again before corruption.

So, I was wondering, is it repairable or should I just replace it with a new hard drive?

My laptop is an HP ENVY x360.

Comment: Looks like a virus... or maybe MBR sector is unstable - try to remap.

Comment: @Akina A virus, unless if it was embedded in the recovery partition or a rootkit which is extremely unlikely given the circumstances, should have been erased with the factory reset, and remapping the MBR sector due to instability is unnecessary, would just be best to replace entirely due to presence of bad sectors indicating failure.

Comment: *remapping the MBR sector due to instability is unnecessary, would just be best to replace entirely due to presence of bad sectors* Unstable sector (weak bit) is not detected as bad sector. And I don't know user-level software which allows to remap custom sector, for example. From the other side, look at 2nd screenshot - this is BIOS message, and it is about not physical but logical error detected. Either MBR (55AA or partition type or boot bit in PT entry cleared/altered) or boot (55AA cleared) is damaged.

Comment: >> "...should I just replace it with a new <s>hard drive</s>SSD?"
FTFY   :-)

Comment: That would be the simplest answer.

Comment: Got it replacement it is, appreciate all the answers and suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your hard drive is beginning to display signs of failure, it is probably the best idea to just replace the HDD entirely. It definitely appears to be very unstable and is showing symptoms of imminent failure, so I would just back up all important data and replace the drive.

I would definitely recommend replacing it with an SSD if possible which will yield much faster load times and better responsiveness.